Basic question about deriving MAP estimator
Say we have a random process $X(t, u)$ parametrized by $t$ and $u$ that generates data $x$. We also have a prior on $u$, $p(u)$.
Am I correct in stating that the expression to find the maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate of only $t$ would be
$$
t_{MAP} = \underset{t}{\operatorname{argmax}} \int p(x | t, u) p(u) du = \underset{t}{\operatorname{argmax}} p(x|t)
$$
That is, you'd marginalize the nuisance parameters out, correct?
Now suppose $U\sim \mathcal{N}[\hat{u}, C_u]$ and $X \mid u, t \sim \mathcal{N}[M(t) u, C_x]$.
Is it correct to say that $p(x | t)$ equals the pdf of $M(t) U$? That is,
$$X \mid t \sim \mathcal{N}[M(t)\hat{u}, M(t)C_uM(t)^\top]$$
Stated differently and more generally, does deriving the distribution of $f(U, t)$ (where $f$ is a bijective function) give the same result as the $\int p(x|t, u)p(u)du$?

Perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my Bayesian tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65

@RomkeBontekoe oops, fixed now!

What is $t$ here, another random parameter or a time index?

@JohandeAguas $t$ is a generic parameter.

Hi: the integral gives p(x | t). I'm not sure about the definition of  f(U, t). It's not defined. It looks like possibly the joint dist of U and t ?

@mlofton I meant $f$ to be a generic bijective function, $f(U, t)$ means $U$ is a random variable while $t$'s value is fixed. Edited the question for clarity.

DangerousTim: Hopefully the explanation below helps. I can't answer because I'm not following where the pdf of $M_t U$ comes from ?  What is M(t) ? If the answer below clears it up for you, then don't worry about my question.

@mlofton that's alright, i think that part deserves a post of its own. Thanks!

Okay. I hope that below helped you.

If $t$ is a random parameter, for which Bayesian inference is required, then $t$ should have a prior, $p(t)$, so it can have a posterior and a MAP estimate. In the most general case, $t_{MAP}=\arg\max_t p(t)\int p(x\mid u,t)p(u\mid t)du$.
If $u$ and $t$ are prior-independent, then  $t_{MAP}=\arg\max_t p(t)\int p(x\mid u,t)p(u)du$.
If, on top, $p(t)$ is the uniform distribution, then $t_{MAP}=\arg\max_t \int p(x\mid u,t)p(u)du$.
